# pre and post processes' function in php

Tags: php, function

if have a bunch of functions :

```
function one () { ... }
function two () { ... }
...
function ten () { ... }
```

is there a way to execute a pre and post function for each ten functions above **WITHOUT MODIFY THEM**?

for instance,

```
function one () { print '1'; }
function pre () { print 'start'; }
function post () { print 'finish'; }

set_pre_function (one, pre);
set_post_function (one, post);

one();
```

result :

```
start
1
finish
```

Comment: Do want to use only plain ol' PHP? Otherwise is this something that easly can be done with a framework. Or if you use OOP, you can put it in the constructor and destructor.

Comment: so you want to 'hijack' php's native function calls? this is interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this approach?
You will need to add your functions to the class, and make them private or protected, but you call them directly.

```
class prePostClass {
    private $preFunc;
    private $postFunc;

    public function set_pre_function($func) {
        $this->preFunc = $func;
    }

    public function set_post_function($func) {
        $this->postFunc = $func;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if (!is_null($this->preFunc)) {
            $this->preFunc();
        }

        $return = call_user_func_array(__CLASS__ . '->' . $name, $arguments);

        if (!is_null($this->postFunc)) {
            $this->postFunc();
        }

        return $return;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make a usage please ?

Answer (score 1):

try call_user_func :

```
   function callfunc($name,$params=false){
         //Call pre 
         //Call real function
         call_user_func($name,$params);
         //and the last, call post
    }
```

thank @KatrinRaimond  :)

Comment: wow that is what i was searching, +1 because you are from Vietnam I made my studies there, from IFI do you know ?

Comment: @발렌텐 instead of `call_user_func($name,$params)` you can simply write `$name($params);` it's more native-y xD. Also may i add that you should `//Call post` AFTER the user function

Comment: @발렌텐 : I dont know, because i frm Saigon :D
KatrinRaimond : Yeb, it's other way (y)

Answer (score 0):

Like this.  I haven't used it but its supposed to work.

```
function one () 
{ 
  global $pre_one;
  global $post_one;
  $pre_one();
  /* code here */
  $post_one();
  }

func_one() { }
func_two() {}

$pre_one = 'func_one';
$post_one = 'func_two';
```

Comment: thanks for your support, I think your solution is good as I can easily change the post and pre functions, however I should have mentioned my intention not to change the ten functions. I want to bind post and pre functions to them without any inner modifications in them.

Answer (score -2):

You can accomplish this by simply calling your relevant `pre` and `post` functions at the beginning and end of the `one` function. That is, if they *need* to be their own functions.

```
function pre () { print 'start'; }
function post () { print 'finish'; }
function one () { pre(); print '1'; post(); }
one();
```

Comment: And how will he be able to change `pre();` in the function `one()` dynamically?

Comment: This is under the assumption he does not plan on swapping out `pre` and `post` dynamically as it wasn't stated in the original question. Rather, as it stands, it appears he simply wants to factor out blocks of code into their own functions.

Comment: For what should then this be: `set_pre_function (one, pre);` ?

Comment: A lack of understanding that it is possible to call functions from within other functions.

Comment: @RyanLombardo if I am not aware of that then I should probably go and find a new job.

Comment: "is there a way to execute a pre and post function for each ten functions above ?" If you read that right, he wants to have a setUp and a tearDown. You would need to put those 2 functions in every function that he have, if you follow your way...

Comment: We can only base answers off what you've provided in the questions. Assumptions about the knowledge of the person cannot be assumed.

Comment: @Blaatpraat Similarly he would have to write `set_pre_function` and `set_post_function` for all ten as well. Resulting in the same number of changes assuming such a function existed.